# Get utc offset from timezone in Javascript

Tags: javascript, timezone, datejs

I need a Javascript function that given a timezone, returns the current UTC offset.

For example, `theFuncIneed('US/Eastern') -> 240`

Comment: Create an object with the timezone names as properties and the offset as value. Note that there is no standard for timezone names, they change from time to time and there are duplicates (e.g. EST).

Comment: Check out moment.js, it has a `zone()` method.

Comment: @RobG - `US/Eastern` is a valid [IANA time zone](http://iana.org/time-zones) identifier.  You can find it near the bottom of the list [here](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_tz_database_time_zones).

Comment: @MattJohnson—I'm not sure what your point is. IANA provide timezone offsets for particular locations. IANA data isn't a standard or even authoritative and there is no pretence that it is (the header of the data file says "This data is by no means authoritative; if you think you know better, go ahead and edit the file").

Comment: @RobG - Agreed. The IANA time zone database not a standard in the way that ISO 8601 is a standard.  But it's a *de facto standard* by convention that it's used ubiquitously throughout multiple operating systems, programming languages, and libraries.  So while there are no *guarantees*, it's still highly likely that `US/Eastern` will be recognized by all implementations.

Comment: @MattJohnson—I think this is way off track. My point was to caution that there is no standard for timezone designators. The IANA database includes a number of exceptions for the timezone observed in a place compared to its geographic location and for the start and end of daylight saving where it's contrary to "official" dates.

Answer (score 16):

It has become possible nowaday with [Intl API](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Intl):

The implementation of `Intl` is based on [icu4c](https://unicode-org.github.io/icu-docs/apidoc/released/icu4c/). If you dig the source code, you'll find that timezone name differs per locale, for example:

```js
for (const locale of ["ja", "en", "fr"]) {
  const timeZoneName = Intl.DateTimeFormat(locale, {
    timeZoneName: "short",
    timeZone: "Asia/Tokyo",
  })
    .formatToParts()
    .find((i) => i.type === "timeZoneName").value;
  console.log(timeZoneName);
}
```

Fortunately, there is a locale, [Interlingua](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Interlingua) (the langauge tag is `ia`), which uses the same pattern (ex. `GMT+11:00`) for timezone names.

The snippet below can meed your need:

```js
const getOffset = (timeZone) => {
  const timeZoneName = Intl.DateTimeFormat("ia", {
    timeZoneName: "short",
    timeZone,
  })
    .formatToParts()
    .find((i) => i.type === "timeZoneName").value;
  const offset = timeZoneName.slice(3);
  if (!offset) return 0;

  const matchData = offset.match(/([+-])(\d+)(?::(\d+))?/);
  if (!matchData) throw `cannot parse timezone name: ${timeZoneName}`;

  const [, sign, hour, minute] = matchData;
  let result = parseInt(hour) * 60;
  if (sign === "+") result *= -1;
  if (minute) result += parseInt(minute);

  return result;
};

console.log(getOffset("US/Eastern")); // 240
console.log(getOffset("Atlantic/Reykjavik")); // 0
console.log(getOffset("Asia/Tokyo")); // -540
```

This way can be a little tricky but it works well in my production project. I hope it helps you too :)

### Update

Many thanks to Bort for pointing out the typo. I have corrected the snippet.

Comment: There's a typo at `if (minute) result + parseInt(minute);`. Should that be `+=`?

Comment: Also this does not take into account daylight saving time changes.

Comment: This does not work for the values in the example - returns 0 for "US/Eastern" and "Atlantic/Reykjavik"

Comment: @Avraham This returns `0` for `getOffset("Atlantic/Reykjavik")` because that’s the current offset of that time zone to UTC. For `getOffset("US/Eastern")` it returns `240`, not `0`.

Comment: @kleinfreund Strange, when I run the second code snippet, I get `0` for `console.log(getOffset("US/Eastern"));`

Comment: @Avraham What does `Intl.DateTimeFormat("ia", { timeZoneName: "short", timeZone: "US/Eastern", }).formatToParts().find((i) => i.type === "timeZoneName").value` return for you? Perhaps something that’s *not* starting with `"GMT"`? And if so, are you running this in a browser or perhaps a Node.js environment?

Comment: For me `timeZoneName` will be `MESZ` in Chrome and this leads to `Cannot parse timezone name`. Input: `Europe/Zurich`. In Firefox it works.

Comment: Changing `timeZoneName: "short",` to `timeZoneName: "shortOffset",` seems to fix this snippet so it works in Chrome 100, Firefox 99, and Node 18. I haven't tested other browsers or node versions. Otherwise, specifying a timezone of "US/Eastern" returns a timeZoneName of "EDT" which does not contain a parseable GMT offset.

Comment: genius thanks, combined with ` Intl.supportedValuesOf('timeZone')` you can filter out list of zone given an offset

Comment: There's a mistake in sign/minute rows. It should be `if (minute) result += parseInt(minute);` first and then `if (sign === "+") result *= -1;` Otherwise all the timezone offsets which have minutes are calculated incorrectly. For example, Asia/Calcutta offset is 5.5 meaning it should be -330 but your code gives -270.

Comment: Also daylight time is not used in the provided function.

Comment: The correct way is to send a date altogether with the timezone and substitute the value into `formatToParts`.

Comment: Got 0, 0, -540 on console logs, also tried, America/New_York and got 0 and US/Central and got 0. I need this exact type of thing but this is not working for me in Chrome.

Answer (score 10):

*In general*, this is not possible.

- `US/Eastern` is an identifier for a *time zone*.  (It's actually an alias to `America/New_York`, which is the real identifier.)
- `240` is a time zone *offset*.  It's more commonly written as `-04:00`  (Invert the sign, divide by 60).
- The US Eastern Time Zone is comprised of both Eastern Standard Time, which has the offset of `-05:00` and Eastern Daylight Time, which has the offset of `-04:00`.

So it is not at all accurate to say `US/Eastern` = 240.  Please read the [timezone tag wiki](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/timezone/info), especially the section titled "Time Zone != Offset".

Now you did ask for the *current* offset, which *is* possible.  If you supply a date+time reference, then you can resolve this.

- For the local time zone of the computer where the javascript code is executing, this is built in with `.getTimezoneOffset()` from any instance of a `Date` object.
- But if you want it for a *specific* time zone, then you will need to use [one of the libraries I listed here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/15171030/634824).

Comment: ECMA-262 defines [timezone offset](http://ecma-international.org/ecma-262/5.1/#sec-15.9.5.26) as `UTC - localTime` expressed in minutes. So I think it's reasonable in a javascript forum to write `+240` where `-04:00` might otherwise be used.

Comment: `.getTimeZoneOffset()` should be `.getTimezoneOffset()` without the uppercase Z

Answer (score 6):

Following function can be used to return the UTC offset given a timezone:

```
const getTimezoneOffset = (timeZone, date = new Date()) => {
  const tz = date.toLocaleString("en", {timeZone, timeStyle: "long"}).split(" ").slice(-1)[0];
  const dateString = date.toString();
  const offset = Date.parse(`${dateString} UTC`) - Date.parse(`${dateString} ${tz}`);
  
  // return UTC offset in millis
  return offset;
}
```

It can be used like:

```
const offset = getTimezoneOffset("Europe/London");
console.log(offset);
// expected output => 3600000
```

Comment: This is slightly incorrect. The UTC offset should be positive for timezones that are behind it, and negative for timezones that are ahead of it. Therefore, the subtraction needs to be reversed:
`Date.parse(\`${dateString} ${tz}\`) - Date.parse(\`${dateString} UTC\`);`. Otherwise, it won't align with the built-in `Date.prototype.getTimezoneOffset`.

Comment: Also, expected output for `"Europe/London"` should be `0`

Comment: @Avraham the offset depends on date due to DST. That's why the function takes a date as the second argument

Comment: timeStyle is invalid. It should be `timeZoneName`

Comment: Results in `NaN` for me.

Comment: @dude `timeStyle` is not [compatible](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Intl/DateTimeFormat/DateTimeFormat#browser_compatibility) with all browsers. `timeZoneName` is a good option, it's compatible with lower version of browser.

Comment: @ranjan_purbey, apparently date.parse('date string') does not universally handle the format of date string you are passing it. https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date/toUTCString
Made a new solution based on your idea but reworked it to be based on a passed date (a future date can have a different offset then a current date) and not utilizing date.parse

Answer (score 1):

You can do this using moment.js

> moment.tz('timezone name').utcOffset()

Although this involves using moment-timezone.js

Comment: you must also have installed the moment-timezone package

Answer (score -1):

The answer of @ranjan_purbey results in `NaN` for me and the answer of @Weihang Jian throws an exception in Chrome (but works in Firefox).

Therefore, based on all the answers I came up with the following function which is basically a combination of both answers working together successfully for me:

```js
function getTimeZoneOffset(timeZone) {
    const date = new Date().toLocaleString('en', {timeZone, timeZoneName: 'short'}).split(' ');
    const timeZoneName = date[date.length - 1];
    const offset = timeZoneName.slice(3);
    if (!offset) {
      return 0;
    }
    const matchData = offset.match(/([+-])(\d+)(?::(\d+))?/);
    if (!matchData) {
      throw new Error(`Cannot parse timezone name: ${timeZoneName}`);
    }
    const [, sign, hour, minute] = matchData;
    let result = parseInt(hour, 10) * 60;
    if (sign === '+') {
      result *= -1;
    }
    if (minute) {
      result += parseInt(minute, 10);
    }
    return result;
}
```

Comment: I do not get the timezone offset for New York, it just says EDT (vs UTC-4 or GMT-5)

Comment: This does not work.  There is no offset value.