# Date issue in angular

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs, datetime

I'm using HTML5 date picker. 
After choosing the date the ng-model shows older date rather the current date selected.

```
<input type="date" ng-model="dateModel" />
```

When I choose current date ng-model has 2015-05-13T18:30:00.000Z instead of 2015-05-14.
If I use in jQuery it stores properly as 2015-05-14

How can I resolve this?

[Plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/vXRmp8N5cHmzXO4EIzsD?p=preview) - AngularJS

[Plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/H7wmugPLS0MSg646wvoY?p=preview) - jQuery

Answer (score 8, accepted):

This is the correct date for your Angular version, however the date is formatted to UTC which could appear to be wrong if you are not fully aware of this.

> The timezone is always zero UTC offset, as denoted by the suffix "Z".

[UTC Source](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date/toISOString)

Look into Angular [date filters](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/filter/date). There are many options out of the box and just about any format you wish can be obtained - but most importantly, resolved to your time zone. For example...

```
{{dateModel | date:'shortDate'}}  // -- prints 5/14/15
{{dateModel | date:'yyyy-MM-dd'}} // -- prints 2015-05-14
```

[Plunker Link](http://plnkr.co/edit/8m2gkIbjTc2SP93pmLHa?p=preview)

---

More about explicitely providing a `timezone` paramater and trusting the browser to resolve our time (Angular docs)

```
{{ date_expression | date : format : timezone }}  // -- template binding
$filter('date')(date, format, timezone)           // -- javascript
```

> Timezone to be used for formatting. It understands UTC/GMT and the
>   continental US time zone abbreviations, but for general use, use a
>   time zone offset, for example, '+0430' (4 hours, 30 minutes east of
>   the Greenwich meridian) If not specified, the timezone of the browser
>   will be used.

---

If your preference is to explicitly define a timezone with [ngModelOptions](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngModelOptions) rather than leveraging filters, you can do so with the following

```
<input type="date" 
    ng-model="dateModel" 
    ng-model-options="{timezone: timezone}" />
```

```
var date = new Date()
$scope.timezone = ((date.getTimezoneOffset() / 60) * -100) // e.g. -400 EDT
```

See [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/20712979/1464112) which explains logic behind the manual calculation

[Plunker Link](http://plnkr.co/edit/YuBKgwj13fkHwtA7cfUc?p=preview) - with `ng-model-options`

Comment: I don't want to use a filter rather use ng-model-options

Comment: @user1184100 Any reason why? Just curious. Anyways, updated answer for you which includes this

Comment: Filter is used only for the display but the data in ng-model is saved to db so that's the reason I would prefer ng-model-options

Comment: It's not required to multiply it with 100. "-3" is treated as "-0300".

Answer (score 1):

AngularJS sets the model to the UTC date-time. I think this is the issue you need to check: http://github.com/angular/angular.js/issues/8447

So for my timezone if I set `ng-model-options="{timezone: '-0200'}"` on the input I get the same date-time as the jQuery version: http://plnkr.co/edit/Qesmucv4aU5Yqu9sxbtp?p=preview

Comment: I did $scope.timezone = d.getTimezoneOffset(); and changed the html to <input type="date" ng-model="dateModel" ng-model-options="{timezone: timezone}" /> is that all I need to do ?

Comment: You'd need to divide `d.getTimezoneOffset()` by 60, because it returns offset in minutes and you need it in hours.  This works for me: http://plnkr.co/edit/Qesmucv4aU5Yqu9sxbtp?p=preview

Answer (score 1):

```
{{dateModel | date : 'yyyy-MM-dd'}}
// {{ date_expression | date : format : timezone}}
```