# convert date time with timezone to UTC in javascript

Tags: javascript, node.js, datetime, datetime-format

I have a date time string like this `2018-09-10T12:05:00` and I know the timezone associated with the date. Assume timezone available is `Asia/Singapore`. How can I get the UTC date with this info available?

There's no timezone associated with date string itself. First step would be to associated a timezone with date and then convert it into UTC. Suggested answers are close but do not help my case ?

UPDATE:
Still no luck with this.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Convert date to another timezone in JavaScript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10087819/convert-date-to-another-timezone-in-javascript)

Comment: Have a look at https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36112774/calculate-the-utc-offset-given-a-timezone-string-in-javascript

Comment: Have a look at https://stackoverflow.com/questions/948532/how-do-you-convert-a-javascript-date-to-utc

Answer (score 1):

Simply just use this method:

var isoDate = new Date('yourdatehere').toISOString();

Comment: my date is just datetime string `2018-09-10T12:05:00`. When I try this on console I see this `2018-09-10T20:05:00.000Z` which seems incorrect. Also my current timezone is Alaska.