# How to check if Daylight Savings Time is in effect given a timezone?

Tags: javascript, datetime, timezone, dst, timezone-offset

Given any timezone, like `America/New_York`, how can I figure out in JavaScript if DST (Daylight Savings Time) is in effect? I'm looking for a solution that does not use any big libraries like moment. Using smaller, more specific libraries like [tz-offset](https://www.npmjs.com/package/tz-offset) is fine.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11887934/how-to-check-if-dst-daylight-saving-time-is-in-effect-and-if-so-the-offset

Comment: That question addresses checking if DST is in effect within the local timezone. I’m trying to find out if DST is in effect given any timezone.

Comment: tz-offset library doesn't handle DST correctly, but [Luxon](https://moment.github.io/luxon/) and [Date-fns-tz](https://github.com/marnusw/date-fns-tz) do.  Both are relatively small and support tree-shaking.  You could also adapt the approach [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/36146278/634824) with the one in the link Nathan gave.